# Error in x$setmean(inv) : attempt to apply non-function

Tags: r

I got 2 functions of code here :

```
      makeCacheMatrix <- function(x = matrix()) {
      inv <- NULL
      set <- function(y) {
        x <<- y
        inv <<- NULL
      }
      get <- function() x
      setInverse <- function(inverse) inv <<- inverse
      getInverse <- function() inv
      list(set = set,
           get = get,
           setInverse = setInverse,
           getInverse = getInverse)
    }


cacheSolve <- function(x, ...) {
  ## Return a matrix that is the inverse of 'x'
  inv <- x$getInverse()
  if (!is.null(inv)) {
    message("getting cached data")
    return(inv)
  }
  mat <- x$get()
  inv <- solve(mat, ...)
  x$setInverse(inv)
  inv
}
```

So when I try to test my function, I will provide a little bit more detail at here:

```
> source("makeCacheMatrix.R")
> my_matrix <- makeCacheMatrix(matrix(1:4, 2, 2))
> my_matrix$get()

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1   3
[2,]    2   4

> my_matrix$getInverse()
NULL

> cacheSolve(my_matrix)
Error in x$setmean(inv) : attempt to apply non-function
```

May I know why when I run the function `cacheSolve(my_matrix)`, it will shows up the error like that?

Comment: I cannot reproduce the error, check the file `"makeCacheMatrix.R"`, the posted code works as expected.

Comment: @RuiBarradas oh? I am wondering why I have problem when running that...

Comment: Is there a `setmean` in the file you are `source`ing?